# Status Filter for ListExecutions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

Is there a way to provide multiple values to statusFilter parameter when calling ListExecutions for step function executions?

I need to get all the executions that are not RUNNING.

```
client = boto3.client('stepfunctions')
response = client.list_executions(
        stateMachineArn=STEP_FUNCTION_STATE_MACHINE_ARN,
        #maxResults=3,
        statusFilter="SUCCEEDED|FAILED"
    )
```

When I do it like this, I get an error that only members of ENUM cab be passed.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't, you can either query twice you you can just filter yourself after returning all data. But keep in mind that step functions have a pagination token that you will need to also iterate through.